# JS : .prepend() an option to 2 select doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I hope the title is self explanatory but i'll try to explain my problem nonetheless.

in my HTML file, i have 2 select, with no option. On the page load, a ajax request is performed to fetch some datas. In the `success` callback of my Ajax request, i create an `option` element for every data i just got. I also prepend those newly created option element to both of my `select`, but the only prepend that works is the one done on the last `select`

Here are SC of my code, in this examlple, the option have been prepended on the `into_APPNAME` select only, and not into the `from_APPNAME`. If i would revert the prepend such as

`$("#into_" + repoName).prepend(option)
$("#from_" + repoName).prepend(option)`

only `from_APPNAME` select would have got options in it.

Any ideas what's going on ?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please post your actual code and not images of it.

Comment: `.prepend()` doesn't magically clone the node before adding it to the DOM

Comment: @Ken what does that change ?

Comment: @JorelAmthor It allows people who know what they are doing to help you fix your code more easily instead of coming here and seeing that all you did was post images and they decide to go help someone else who has taken the time to provide their code (like the site guidelines ask for).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create two different HTML elements or clone the first one you created in order to create a new one. This code for example should populate both of them:

```
var option1 = $('<option></option>').attr('value', branch).text(branch);
var option2 = $('<option></option>').attr('value', branch).text(branch);
$("#into_" + repoName).prepend(option1);
$("#from_" + repoName).prepend(option2);
```

Of course better to clone the option1 into the option2

```
var option2 = $(option1).clone();
```

Another way can be the following, getting rid of variables:

```
$("#into_" + repoName).prepend($('<option></option>').attr('value', branch).text(branch));
$("#from_" + repoName).prepend($('<option></option>').attr('value', branch).text(branch));
```